# .Net Get instance of Program.cs registered class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am reworking an old app and want to implement dependancy injection. Though I cannot rework everything at once and would like to retrieve an instance of a class registered in the `program.cs` like so (one of them, not all at once of course)

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
services.AddScoped<MyClass>();
```

I want to access an instance of `MyClass` in a class where I can not implement regular dependancy injection (everything is Newed with fix argument and I'd have to change everything for it to be possible, so not an option).

Is there a way to get an instance of my class a bit like so:

```cs
MyClass myInstance = GetInstance(getType(MyClass));
```

On top of that I have some places where I want to dynamically get a different version of an interface depending on some params.

```
public void myFunc(string className)
{
   var type = Type.GetType("myNamespace." + className);
   IMyClass myClass = GetInstance(getType(type));
   myClass.DoSomething();
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do so ?  (remember that regular dependancy injection in the constructor is not an option)

**EDIT:**
`new MyClass()` is of course not an option because if I want to use dependancy injection is because I want to have all the bells and whistles that come with it and especially having a lot of parameters in my constructor a bit like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly IOptions<MyOption> _options;

    public MyClass(
        ILogger<MyClass> logger
        , IMemoryCache memoryCache
        , IOptions<MyOption> options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _options = options;
    }
}
```

And I'd have to have all the instances of `logger` `option` and `memory` cache to be able to new

Comment: Are you calling the method `myFunc` from a place where you do have dependency injection? Otherwise, you can give your dependency to the method as a parameter when calling it, but you would have to make sure the place where you call the function isn't being disposed since otherwise the service you gave to the method would be disposed as well, which will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the factory design pattern because your method is not very good. But you can solve this problem by using multiple interfaces for this question but I don't suggest it.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    void DoSomething();
}
public interface ISingletoneState : IMyClass
{
}
public interface IScopedState : IMyClass
{
}
public class MyClass : ISingletoneState, IScopedState
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        /*your code*/
    }
}
```

then add your di

```
services.AddScoped<IScopedState,MyClass>();
services.AddSingleton<ISingletoneState,MyClass>();
services.AddTransient<IMyClass,MyClass>();
```

now use its :

```
var scodeInstance=services.GetService<IScopedState>();
var singletonInstance=services.GetService<ISingletoneState>();
var transientInstance=services.GetService<IMyClass>();
```

Comment: Where do you get `services` from, when I want to retrieve my instance i'm not in Program.cs

Comment: In .net 6 , Your code can be runned in hosted service or after call app. Build() . But I don't know that what are you using of technology?

Comment: I want to acces it outside of program/startup, that's my problem. it's easy to get the instance in program.cs but I want to access it from anywhere